# Create a simple extension which adds 1 field to the category

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, category

I need to create a very simple extension to add just one text field in the category on the backend and show it on the category view on the frontend.

What steps should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own module with the following files.

**`app/etc/modules/[Namespace]_[Module].xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <[Namespace]_[Module]>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </[Namespace]_[Module]>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`** - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]/[Module]>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </[Namespace]/[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <[namespace]_[module]_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>[Namespace]_[Module]</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </[namespace]_[module]_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/sql/[namespace]_[module]_setup/install-0.0.1.php`** - the install script

```
<?php 
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'attribute_code_here', array(
    'group'     => 'General', //tab name where it should go - use General or General Information - if the tab does not exist it will be created
    'type'              => 'varchar', //the type of the attribute
    'backend'           => '', //a backend model if needed
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Attribute label here',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '', //a source model if needed - only for selects or multiselects
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, //attribute scope
    'visible'           => true, 
    'frontend_class'    => '',
    'required'          => false, //required or not
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'unique'            => false, //unique or not
    'note'              => 'Text that appears under the field. Leave empty if not needed.'
));
$this->endSetup();
```

Clear the cache and refresh any page.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now how can I make this a zip installer file?

Comment: Also, how can I delete this extension?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out myself via the Package Manager.

Comment: Hello,this is not working to me, any tip? I did clear caches, delete folders in /var but still now... no lucky... my Magento ver. is 1.8.1.0

Comment: another comment is regardin the file config.xml, is it correct wi the ´/´ inside the modules node?